# Handling concurrent login using cookie based authentication in rest assured java

Tags: java, authentication, cookies, rest-assured

In my TestNG framework with Rest Assured and java,
cookie based authentication is used to login to a web application.

It returns a cookie and authenticity token and have used synchronized on the login method, but when the tests run together on jenkins pipeline, it sometimes fails to make a hit because of concurrent login..

Any other suggestions other than "Synchronized" would be highly appreciated

Let me know if you require any other information

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to perform "login" step **before** the entire test suite execution, assign returned cookies to a var and pass the value where cookies is passed in.
**Only after that**, start the actual test execution.

Based on your test runner (JUnit or TestNG), pseudo-code is following:

```
  public class BaseTest {

         @BeforeSuite
         public void fetchCookies() {
              // do login stuff
         }
    
         @BeforeTest
         public void feedCookies() {
              // pass fetched cookies into the rest-assured client
         }  
    
         // run test afterwards
    }
```